# Why HTML page is not generating and not requested for a, supposedly, SSG page in NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, static-site-generation

I have a static route page, say **myPage**, that I want to be statically generated during build time as SSG.
When I run the build I see that **myPage** is marked as SSG in console.
On my local I do not see `myPage.html` but `myPage.js` inside `.next/server/`.
Also when I open that page in browser I do not see a document type request for myPage instead I see requests for a json and js file.
What could be wrong? `myPage` is a static route and I am using `getStaticProps` with `revalidate: 100 * 10`